# Finding binary combinations based on substitute wildcards

Tags: c#, recursion

I am given a string containing the possible characters of : `0`, `1`, and `?`, iterating over possibilities, replacing the wildcard `?` with either `0` or `1`.

For example; given `"1?00?101"`, the outcome would be: `["10000101", "10001101", "11000101", "11001101"]`.

My code seems to work, I tested with two wildcards and three wildcards, but is there a better way to solve this.

```
class MainClass
    {
        static void BinaryString(char [] word, int a, int b, int count){
            if (count == 0) {
                Console.WriteLine (word);
            } else {
                for (int i = a; i < b; i++) {
                    if (word [i].Equals ('?')) {
                        word [i] = '0';
                        count--;
                        BinaryString (word, i, word.Length - 1, count);
                        word [i] = '1';
                        BinaryString (word, i, word.Length - 1, count);
                        word [i] = '?';
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            string binary = "1?00?1?1";
            char[] bi = binary.ToCharArray ();
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < bi.Length; i++) {
                if (bi [i].Equals ('?')) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            BinaryString (bi, 0, bi.Length - 1, count);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Naming**

`a` and `b` don't really convey anything.  You should use descriptive names like `startIndex` and `endIndex`.  Method names should be verbs.

**Spacing**

You should have consistent spacing.  You have `char[]` in one place and `char []` in another.  You also have no space before an opening brace and have a space before the other opening braces.

**Safety and Readability**

You should favor safety and readability over performance.  Premature optimization is not a good thing.  If, after writing safe and readable code, you're having performance issues, use a profiler to find the bottleneck and optimize that.  You're passing in a bunch of parameters to your `BinaryString` method and mutating a char array to make sure you don't search through the char array more than necessary, but this is hard to read and can easily lead to bugs.  I believe you have a bug where if the last character is a wildcard nothing will get printed out.  I suggest working with a string instead of a char array and using a helper method that returns a new string with the first wildcard replaced (some good implementations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141045/how-do-i-replace-the-first-instance-of-a-string-in-net)).  This uses more memory and might take longer, but you can always optimize it later if it turns out to be a bottleneck.

**Single Responsibility Principle**

The `BinaryString` method should return a list of strings.  Then you can iterate through that list and print each one out.

Here is the updated code:

```
class MainClass
{
    private static IEnumerable<string> GetVariations(string word)
    {
        if(!word.Any(c => c.Equals('?')))
        {
            return new[] { word };
        } 
        else
        {
            string newWord1 = ReplaceFirstMatch(word, "?", "0");
            string newWord2 = ReplaceFirstMatch(word, "?", "1");
            return GetVariations(newWord1).Concat(GetVariations(newWord2));                
        }
    }

    private static string ReplaceFirstMatch(string theString, string oldValue, string newValue)
    {
        int loc = theString.IndexOf(oldValue);
        if(loc < 0)
        {
            return theString;
        }
        return theString.Remove(loc, oldValue.Length).Insert(loc, newValue);
    }

    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        string binary = "1?00?1?1";            
        foreach(string variation in GetVariations(binary))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(variation);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need a `var` or `string` in front of `newWord1` and `newWord2`

Comment: Nicely done. I think I'd have `GetVariations` `yield` the results as they come in. No need to `Concat` them then.

Comment: @RobH: Good catch!  Fixed.

Comment: @Mat'sMug: Because `Concat` is lazy, wouldn't it be essentially the same as yielding the results as they come in?  There's also the tradeoff of having to write two `foreach` loops.

Comment: Would probably be the same indeed. I just can't help thinking `yield` whenever I see `IEnumerable<T>` as a return type ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug - I almost wrote that up as an aswer before noticing how similar it would be to this one.

Comment: Good answer.  Could be better if you incorporated some of @Mat'sMug suggestions of moving `Main` to the top, and using a constant named `Wildcard`.  Your text doesn't mention it out right but your code does use access modifiers on each method declaration (+1).

Answer (score 7):

Let's get the obvious out of the way first.

## Style.

The first thing that hits me is the indentation being offset here:

> ```
> class MainClass
>     {
> ```

Should be:

```
class MainClass
{
```

The next thing that hits me (in the same millisecond, really), is the inconsistent braces. You have them next-line-style at class level, and anything under class scope has them same-line-style. It's.... annoying to read. C# typically uses next-line braces:

```
if (count == 0) 
{
    Console.WriteLine (word);
} 
else 
{
    ...
}
```

Also, it seems like you're fighting your IDE here:

> ```
> char[] bi = binary.ToCharArray ();
> ```

And here:

> ```
> if (bi [i].Equals ('?'))
> ```

These spaces feel very awkward. C# reads better like this:

```
char[] bi = binary.ToCharArray();
```

```
if (bi[i].Equals('?'))
```

The last thing, and perhaps the most important one, is about method ordering: code should read like a book, and unveil like a story. Just like you wouldn't start reading a story at the end, a class' code shouldn't start with its implementation details - I expect `void Main` to be the first thing: that's where everything starts, after all.

---

## Abstractions & Responsibilities.

Programming is about *making abstractions* - the *abstraction level* of `Main` is too low, it's not clear what that loop is there for and what's being counted: `count` isn't exactly the most meaningful name to use here. You're counting question marks, and question marks are a thing in the context of this app. Why isn't there a concept of `wildcard` anywhere?

```
private static readonly char Wildcard = '?';
```

You have a loop in `Main`, that's counting the wildcards. You could extract a method to better express that intent, but it's probably simpler to inline a bit of LINQ there - note that `ToCharArray()` is completely useless, since a `string` can already be iterated as an `IEnumerable<char>` in C#:

```
var wildcardCount = binary.Count(c => c.Equals(Wildcard));
```

Notice how much easier it is to figure out exactly what's going on - and why.

Now, looking at the `BinaryString` method (bad name, methods should start with a verb, they're *actions*), I'm questioning *why* you would need to pass in the `wildcardCount` as a parameter, when all it's used for is really to exit the looping/recursion logic - you already have that information in the character array itself:

```
if (!word.Any(c => c.Equals(Wildcard)))
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

Ah.. and now I see why `ToCharArray` was used - the method returning `void`, your entire logic depends on the ability to mutate array elements! That smells funky, because parameters are passed by value. A much more idiomatic way, in my opinion, would be to take a `string` input, and return a new `string` after processing.

That would make it easier to leave the console output out of the function's logic, too - I don't like that the function is responsible for producing/computing the string (/mutating the character array) *and* producing the output. It just feels wrong, clearly it breaks the *Single Responsibility Principle*.